# Is it possible to load a control by name using binding?

Tags: wpf, binding, controls

In my application I need a collection of different I/O devices e.g. Serial, OPC, USB devices etc. I have used the MEF framework to provide a way of handling the collection and allowing new devices to be added.

My project looks something like this:

```
Atf.Model     'contains the model
Atf.Gui       'the views and view-models
Atf.Devices   'contains implementations of IDevice and exports them
```

Many devices need configuration so the device interface exposes a path to a custom control and the corresponding view-model which handle the editing of the device configuration. I am trying to stick to the MVVM pattern and want to separate the view and model as far as possible. At the same time I want to keep the coupling to the device collection as loose as possible.

In `Atf.Gui` I have a control which displays all the discovered devices and displays the activated devices. When an activated device is selected I want to display its' editor dynamically.

How might I do this? Here are some (crazy) ideas:

**Idea-1** Simply load a `UserControl` in my view-model using the path in the device object. This would break the MVVM separation and render that part 'untestable'

```
public System.Windows.Controls.UserControl ConfigureControl 
{
   get 
   {
       // code to load the UserControl using the path property
   }
}
```

**Idea-2** Have the device expose only a view-model and use mapping (defined in the device repository) to pick up the view. Not sure how this would be done.

```
<myeditorcontainer>
    <ContainerControl Content="{Binding CurrentlySelectedDeviceViewModel}"/>
</myeditorcontainer>
```

**Idea-3** In my view, load a control using binding. Not sure if this is possible at all.

```
<myeditorcontainer>
    <UserControl Path="{Binding CurrentlySelectedDeviceViewPath}" 
                 DataContext="{Binding CurrentlySelectedDeviceViewModel}"/>
</myeditorcontainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that Idea 2 is the way to go.

Assuming that `ContainerControl` derives from `ContentControl`, you should be able to specify a `DataTemplate` for each type of view model that you'll show, and then the correct UI will be rendered based on the type of the view model. For example:

```
<myeditorcontainer>
    <ContainerControl Content="{Binding CurrentlySelectedDeviceViewModel}">
        <ContainerControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel1Type}">
                <!-- controls for ViewModel1's UI -->
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel2Type}">
                <!-- controls for ViewModel2's UI -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContainerControl.Resources>
    </ContainerControl>
</myeditorcontainer>
```

If you need more flexibility than the type of the view model in order to decide which template to use, you can specify a [ContentTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It will return the correct template to use based on whatever criteria you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in the end and it seems to work ok. The key features are that the view-model has the same name as the view but with 'Model' appended and that the view-models derive from a particular class - DeviceSettingsBase.

The XAML:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ConfigControl}"/>
```

The View-Model:

```
private RequiredDeviceViewModel rdvm;

public ContentControl ConfigControl
{
    get
    {
        // get assembly which contains this object
        Assembly assy = Assembly.GetAssembly(rdvm.Device.GetType());
        // get View-Type using the name defined in the Device
        Type viewType = assy.GetType(rdvm.Device.ConfigureControlResourceName, true);
        // get ViewModel-Type using the viewname + Model (may be null)
        Type viewModelType = assy.GetType(rdvm.Device.ConfigureControlResourceName + "Model", false);

        // instantiate the view control
        ContentControl view = (ContentControl)Activator.CreateInstance(viewType);
        // instantiate viewModel - if type not null
        if (viewModelType != null)
        {
            object viewModel = (object)Activator.CreateInstance(viewModelType, new object[] { rdvm.RequiredDevice.Config.ConfigString });
            view.DataContext = viewModel;
            // all device viewModels must derive from DeviceSettingsBase
            CurrentConfigViewModel = viewModel as DeviceSettingsBase;
            if (CurrentConfigViewModel != null)
            {
                CurrentConfigViewModel.IsEditable = IsEditable;
                CurrentConfigViewModel.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(vmb_PropertyChanged);
                CurrentConfigViewModel.SettingsChanged += new SettingsChangedHandler(vmb_SettingsChanged);
            }
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```